# Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router::middleware()

Tags: laravel, lumen, laravel-passport

After the artisan command **composer require  dusterio/lumen-passport** the error comes **Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router::middleware()**
I dont know why this error occured

I am trying to installing the passport package on laravel lumen framework but because of the error nothing happened

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems similar to this issue:

https://github.com/dusterio/lumen-passport/issues/175

Try to follow this:

```
Localized problem, it is some incompatibility with the new version of Passport v11. Adding in composer.json the following line works correctly with Lumen 9:

"laravel/passport": "^10.4"
```

Comment: I' m getting the same error but at new lumen version adding "laravel/passport" to composer wasn't solved the problem.